# Webpack worker-loader versus worker-plugin

Tags: webpack, web-worker, worker-loader

What are the benefits of using worker-plugin compared to worker-loader for workers in webpack, and why? Which one is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary difference is that Worker-Plugin allows you to write completely standard syntax that would run without Webpack, and bundles it behind the scenes. Worker-Loader introduces its own API (though it is a simple one) that is specific to Webpack.